# php foreach multidimensional/nested array to get all data

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a array like this

```
Array ( 
[group-a] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [j_paket] => Kuota 
        [nama_paket] => sa 
        [harga] => 21 
        [deskripsi] => test ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [j_paket] => Kuota 
        [nama_paket] => dsd 
        [harga] => 213 
        [deskripsi] => sada ) 
))
```

and i have a foreach

```
foreach ($post as $grop => $single) {
    foreach($single as $has){
        $data = array(
            'j_paket' => $has['j_paket'],
            'nama_paket' => $has['nama_paket'],
            'harga' => $has['harga'],
            'deskripsi' => $has['deskripsi'],
            'date_created' => $now,
            'status' => "Active"
        );
    }
}
```

error :

> **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

please help me solve this problem

Comment: Where is this error being reported on, the 1st for-loop or the second one?

Comment: the error is a second foreach

Comment: after first foreach check `if(is_array($single) || is_object($single))`

Comment: @IrfanAlviansyah Why should the error be a second `foreach`?

Comment: before foreach(), print_r($post) and show us what you found, hope your $post is not an array

Comment: in my code $post is a array `Array ( 
[group-a] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [j_paket] => Kuota 
        [nama_paket] => sa 
        [harga] => 21 
        [deskripsi] => test ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [j_paket] => Kuota 
        [nama_paket] => dsd 
        [harga] => 213 
        [deskripsi] => sada ) 
))`

Comment: if this is so, then i don't think so any error comes check here https://eval.in/845192 the running code with out getting any error, according to me $post is not an array

Comment: @BunkerBoy in my codeigniter show the error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: array concept is same every where

Comment: @BunkerBoy the array is true but my codeigniter show a error like that

Comment: Really sorry man i did not use codeigniter ever but i think there is no issue with foreach() it's fine about this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` it comes only when foreach() does not get array as an argument

Comment: Indeed, either `$post` or `$single` is not an array. Maybe it's `null` or something. Check your variable types. You can use function 'is_array()'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This,

$newArr = array();

foreach($post as $pKey => $pVal){

```
foreach($pVal as $k => $has){

    $data = array(
        'j_paket' => $has['j_paket'],
        'nama_paket' => $has['nama_paket'],
        'harga' => $has['harga'],
        'deskripsi' => $has['deskripsi'],
        'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'status' => "Active"
    );

    $newArr[] = $data;
}
```

}

print_r($newArr);

Comment: is return a true value like this : `Array ( [0] => Array ( [j_paket] => Kuota [nama_paket] => sa [harga] => 21 [deskripsi] => saad [date_created] => 2017-08-14 15:53:37 [status] => Active ) [1] => Array ( [j_paket] => Kuota [nama_paket] => dsd [harga] => 213 [deskripsi] => sada [date_created] => 2017-08-14 15:53:37 [status] => Active ) )`                                                 but in my codeigniter have a error `message : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: The query in your model is returning either string or object data, instead of an array. 
 
Could you show me a code example to illustrate ?

Comment: If post data is string , then this type of error generate else it execute successfully

Comment: how to post $newArr to query database?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (j_paket, nama_paket, harga, deskripsi,date_created,status)
  VALUES  
  foreach($newArr as $nKey => $nVal){
   ($nVal['j_paket'], $nVal['nama_paket'], $nVal['harga'],$nVal['deskripsi'],$nVal['date_created'],$nVal['status'])";
  }